# How to get file from USB using Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Browse button like this:
[browse file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAwdY.png)
when I click this button, a windows is open and allow select file from my laptop.
But I want to get file from usb, how can I open the correct USB folder containing the file?

Comment: You can't tell the file browser where to start looking. The user has to navigate to the file manually. The browser does this intentionally to keep malicious sites from trying to index your system.

Comment: You can't specify a default folder for the `<input type="file" />` (at least in a browser environment). Also, you can't be sure there would be a USB drive attached and you can't know its actual location in the file system (due to platform differences - MacOS, Linux, Windows, Android etc.)

Comment: @TsvetanGanev even ignoring the platform differences - on Windows you cannot know which drive letter a USB is mapped to. E.g., on one machine it might be D on another, it might be F. And if there is any custom mapping done by the user, a given USB might be mapped to only, say, V, another USB to W. So, even just within Windows you cannot "suggest" where to find a USB. On other OSes it's even harder.

Answer (score -1):

In any case, you should mount device as local drive. In windows you must assignt to them drive letter, so then you can select file using standatd open file dialog. You can not communicate directly to USB devices from browser sandbox environment. This is possible only from node.js, or from browser extension with some hacks.